# How to distinguish the two picture matrices?

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, matlab-deployment

I have a picture matrix `A`, the size of which is `200*3000 double`. And I have another picture matrix `B`, the size of which is `200*1000 double`. The `1000` columns of matrix `B` exactly comes from the columns of matrix `A`. My question is:

How to get a matrix `C` with the same size of matrix `A`, but only keep the original values of columns in matrix `B`? I mean the size of matrix `C` is `200*3000 double`, but only `1000` columns have the same values as matrix `B`. The other `2000` columns will be set to another value `d`, that is my second question, what is the value I should set for `d`, so that the picture matrix `C` can distinguish from picture matrix `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option. Here's an example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8]; %// example A
B = [3 10 1; 7 20 5];   %// example B
val = NaN;              %// example value to indicate no match

C = A; %// initiallize
ind = ismember(A.',B.','rows'); %// matching columns
C(:,~ind) = val; %// set non-matching columns to val
```

Equivalently, you coud replace `ismember` by [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), so that line becomes

```
ind = any(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(B, [1 3 2])), 1), 3);
```

In this example,

```
A =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
B =
     3    10     1
     7    20     5
C =
     1   NaN     3   NaN
     5   NaN     7   NaN
```

Comment: I guess you are right, but it is very memory cost.It cannot work in my side because of the memory problem. Is there any other way to avoid the memory problem.